# use Entity Framework for big projects

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Can I Use Entity Framework 6 with .net 4.5 for a big project ?

In this project i have many solution in this project and some of them are in a fast communication with database like as Smtp with hug data communication

thanks

// edit for more details

i start a big project that it has five section

1- send sms with smtp that create huge request and overload on database for example in secound 1500 record insert and select

2- payment request

3- many other request ...

Comment: Your question is to wide, can you explain in more detail? Define *huge* and *fast*.

Comment: you might want to read this SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19311491/how-entity-framework-works-for-large-number-of-records

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default answer, is certainly yes. This is where all ORMs shine. In large systems where writing a data access layer is a big and error prone task.

As [Steve McConnell suggests in his great book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735619670) **you should never make speculations about performance.** Therefore, **if you have specific performance concerns, you should try benchmarking**.

If you want my opinion, between clear code and performance, I choose clear code. It will allow you to implement a more robust and maintainable system. Then, if you identify performance problems, you could make the necessary minor changes. This is my default rule.

Hope I helped!

Answer (score 0):

*Can I Use Entity Framework 6 with .net 4.5 for a big project ?*

Yes

*In this project i have many solution in this project and some of them are in a fast communication with database like as Smtp with hug data communication*

Yes, although it might depend on your database design. And even then you could use Stored Procedures if necessary.